# How to create a panel in CANoe project with selection of the particular ECU from DBC and selection of the TX/RX message from the selected ECU?

Tags: can-bus, capl, canoe, automotive

Once after adding the DBC file to CANoe configuration, How to select the particular ECU from DBC and select the particular TX/RX message in the panel?

Brief: I have multiple ECU 
let's assume there are 3 ECU's
A - ECU1,
B - ECU2,
C - ECU3

I need to select a particular ECU in the panel and need to select the Particular TX message in selected ECU.
GUI for the panel is ready, but I cant create the background logical connection between the DBC file (ECU, Messages selection) and the panel.
(Limitation: Since you can only map the Env/System Variable and Signal).

Is the above scenario is possible? please explain

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Automation sequence in CANoe to do this, which is available for run, full and stand-alone license,

[image]

You can start the visual sequence in always running mode, and check for the value of the system variable in your visual sequence to send the CAN Frame. You can use loops and conditional command blocks (If, Else If, Else, End If) to structure the individual steps, e.g. to send TX message from different ECUs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about dynamic selection of information from DBC, then its difficult.

I think you can parse DBC information as a text information . So you might need to generate a input file with structures or array contains the required data like message name, ECU name from the DBC.

In order to create input file, you might need support of python. 
You can use DBC file as input to python and generate a input file with required data as per your need.
define the logic in python like comparing and fetching the ECU name, Msg name etc.

In CAPL script, you can create logic to show the information from input file according to the User selection.

Note: Python will see the DBC as text file. So use file handling in python and compare each line for the required data. There are lot of API's available in python for line search , split , append etc.

This might help you..